Wrong autoref chapter name after appendix
I'm trying to autoref a chapter that is placed after some appendices, but it's name is "Appendix X" instead of "Chapter X".
For fancyhdr i'am using \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\appendixname \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} for the header, maybe there is a similar command for hyperref ?
Thx for your help !
See MWE here :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}\label{chap1}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{App}\label{App}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}
\end{appendices}

\chapter{chap2}\label{chap2}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

For some unknown reason the appendix package redefines a hyperref command globally and so the change is still in effect after the end of the environment.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chap1}\label{chap1}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{App}\label{App}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}
\end{appendices}

\makeatletter \def\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@chapterstring}\makeatother
\chapter{chap2}\label{chap2}
\autoref{chap1} \autoref{App} \autoref{chap2}

\end{document}


Thx this works perfectly well !
